# Python 2.7 - Multiple threads won't independently continue iteration within same Class

Tags: python, multithreading, io, console

So I have a big class with three functions. One is a web **scraper** , one processes the data, and the other is a UI. All of which run continuously via "**while**" loop. I use threads to run these methods, however, I don't know if its the threads them selves, or the "**raw_input()**" that prevents the while loops to continue its iteration.
and Yes, I know this can be done with a GUI.

```
import os, sys, time, shutil, threading
...
self.threadA = threading.Thread( target=self.PLAY, args=() )
self.threadB = threading.Thread(target=self.DOWNLOAD, args=() )
self.threadA.start()
self.threadB.start()
while True: 
    ## UI
    command = raw_input("Enter a command > ")
```

---

What I have:

- Multiple threads.
- Each thread doesn't continue iteration till the others have finished (i.e The UI)

What I need:

- Each thread to run independtly
- Each thread can still read/write to class variables (i.e "self.ValueA = 'test' " )
- Bonus: UI runs in different window than what other threads print to.

---

Python 2.7 - Windows 8

Comment: Curious how the communication between different threads are done, since the data processing thread needs data from the web scrapper.

Comment: @mengg Well the "Webscrapper" downloads audio files to a "Cache" directory. The other thread Plays those files. However, as mentioned, the while loop seems to stop when the UI invokes "raw_input()". There are only a few variables shared between functions/threads which are stored within the single Class itself.